# How to pass Pardot authentication headers via R

Tags: r, authentication

Following the pardot API instructions (http://developer.pardot.com/#using-the-api), I want to pass my user key and api key via headers in a GET function

`GET https://pi.pardot.com/api/<object>/version/3/do/<op>/<id_field>/<id>?<params> HTTP/1.1 
Authorization: Pardot api_key=<your_api_key>, user_key=<your_user_key>`

I've tried a lot of things already but can't seem to get it to work.

I've tried things like:

```r
GET(url = data_url, add_headers(Authorization = "Pardot", api_key=api_key,user_key=user_key))
```

or

```r
GET(url = data_url, add_headers(Authorization = paste("Pardot ", api_key=api_key,user_key=user_key)))
```

But that doesn't seem to work

I'm hoping to get some feedback on how to use authorization headers in R using the GET function. None of my approaches seem to be legit...

Comment: Hello BroQ, welcome to StackOverflow. Can we see the current output of the get function? It might be useful for a user to see the error trace in order to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the initial feedback!
I've been able to figure it out by myself in the meantime:

```
# Base query URL
data_url <- "https://pi.pardot.com/api/opportunity/version/4/do/query"

# Combine URL with headers
result <- GET(url = data_url, add_headers(Authorization = paste("Pardot api_key=",api_key,",user_key=",user_key)))
```

It was as easy as that...